# Adding Memcached plugin to Mysql Cluster Fails to start

Tags: mysql, ndbcluster, memcached

I was able to setup a new mysql cluster, with total 6 VMs. New requirement is to add memcache plugin to mysql cluster, memcache failing to start with this error message `WARNING  -- Failed to allocate nodeid for API at 192.168.1.100. Returned error: 'No free node id found for mysqld(API).'` .

Here is my existing setup.

```
192.168.1.100 Management1
192.168.1.101 Management2
192.168.1.102 datanode1
192.168.1.103 datanode2
192.168.1.104 sqlnode1
192.168.1.105 sqlnode2
```

I am trying to run memcached on existing sql nodes

> sqlnode1 & sqlnode2

Here is the configuration on management nodes `Management1, Management2`

```
[ndb_mgmd default]
DataDir=/mysql/data

[ndbd default]
NoOfReplicas=2
LockPagesInMainMemory=1
DataMemory=25G
IndexMemory=5G
NoOfFragmentLogFiles=300
DataDir=/mysql/data
MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations=1000000
SchedulerSpinTimer=400
SchedulerExecutionTimer=100
RealTimeScheduler=1
MaxNoOfTables=1024
MaxNoOfOrderedIndexes=256

[ndb_mgmd]
HostName=192.168.1.100
NodeId=51

[ndb_mgmd]
HostName=192.168.1.101
NodeId=52

[ndbd]
HostName=192.168.1.102
NodeId=53

[ndbd]
HostName=192.168.1.103
NodeId=54

[mysqld]
HostName=192.168.1.104
NodeId=55

[mysqld]
HostName=192.168.1.105
NodeId=56

[mysqld]
HostName=192.168.1.104
NodeId=57

[mysqld]
HostName=192.168.1.105
NodeId=58
```

Here is configuration file `/etc/my.conf` on data & sql nodes `datenode1, datanode2, sqlnode1, sqlnode2`.

```
[mysqld]
ndbcluster
ndb-connectstring=192.168.1.100,192.168.1.101
datadir=/mysql/data
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
symbolic-links=0
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

[mysql_cluster]
ndb-connectstring=192.168.1.100,192.168.1.101
```

current status of cluster.

```
#ndb_mgm -e show
Connected to Management Server at: 192.168.1.100:1186
Cluster Configuration
---------------------
[ndbd(NDB)]     2 node(s)
id=53    @192.168.1.102  (mysql-5.7.19 ndb-7.5.7, Nodegroup: 0)
id=54    @192.168.1.103 (mysql-5.7.19 ndb-7.5.7, Nodegroup: 0, *)

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 2 node(s)
id=51    @192.168.1.100  (mysql-5.7.19 ndb-7.5.7)
id=52    @192.168.1.101  (mysql-5.7.19 ndb-7.5.7)

[mysqld(API)]   4 node(s)
id=55    @192.168.1.104  (mysql-5.7.19 ndb-7.5.7)
id=56    @192.168.1.105  (mysql-5.7.19 ndb-7.5.7)
id=57 (not connected, accepting connect from 192.168.1.104)
id=58 (not connected, accepting connect from 192.168.1.105)

#
```

here is the error when I try to add memcache plugin to mysql cluster.
created `ndbmemcache` configuration in database, didnt notice any error.

```
# mysql -u root -p < /usr/share/mysql/memcache-api/ndb_memcache_metadata.sql
Enter password:
#
```

when I start memcached server, it fails with error below.

```
#/usr/sbin/memcached -E /usr/lib64/mysql/ndb_engine.so -u root -e "connectstring=192.168.1.100:1186,192.168.1.101:1186;debug=true" -scheduler=S:c1,f0,t1
main --> ndb_initialize()
main --> connect_to_primary_cluster()
27-Oct-2017 15:35:04 UTC NDB Memcache 5.7.19-ndb-7.5.7 started [NDB 7.5.7; MySQL 5.7.19]
Contacting primary management server (192.168.1.100:1186,192.168.1.101:1186) ...
main --> ClusterConnectionPool::connect()
FAILED.
Could not connect to NDB.  Shutting down.
main --> ndb_destroy()
Failed to initialize instance. Error code: 255
#
```

cluster management logs `ndb_51_cluster.log` show this Warning message.

```
2017-10-27 15:33:44 [MgmtSrvr] WARNING  -- Failed to allocate nodeid for API at 192.168.1.104. Returned error: 'No free node id found for mysqld(API).'
2017-10-27 15:35:06 [MgmtSrvr] WARNING  -- Failed to allocate nodeid for API at 192.168.1.104. Returned error: 'No free node id found for mysqld(API).'
2017-10-27 15:35:09 [MgmtSrvr] WARNING  -- Failed to allocate nodeid for API at 192.168.1.104. Returned error: 'No free node id found for mysqld(API).'
2017-10-27 15:35:12 [MgmtSrvr] WARNING  -- Failed to allocate nodeid for API at 192.168.1.104. Returned error: 'No free node id found for mysqld(API).'
2017-10-27 15:35:15 [MgmtSrvr] WARNING  -- Failed to allocate nodeid for API at 192.168.1.104. Returned error: 'No free node id found for mysqld(API).'
2017-10-27 15:35:18 [MgmtSrvr] WARNING  -- Failed to allocate nodeid for API at 192.168.1.104. Returned error: 'No free node id found for mysqld(API).
```

'

Can someone please suggest how can I fix this issue, I already have additional sql client nodes, but not able to start memcache process.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In the headline the error message says it attempted to allocate
from 192.168.1.100, this would not work since there is no
free API node there.

But in cluster log it seems like the error message implies the
node is connecting from 192.168.1.104 and from there it should
work since there is a free API node there.

Look in the node logs to see if there are any other log
messages that can assist in understanding the issue.